# How I can send a file from my server to an Android app?

Tags: android, networking, upload, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I need to send a file to an Android application from my server. I have the user's IP address saved in a database from the last time he was online.

Does Android have something like listener over the internet so I can send a request (from myserver with the IP) to check if is it the user I am looking for or if the IP has changed?

Comment: How do you want to perform the check if it is the same user you are looking for ? Are you storing any unique identity with the ip as well ? In my opnion it would be better to let the app identify itself rather than server initiating the process of identifying the app

Comment: of course there is an id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into the [Android Cloud to Device Messaging Framework](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/). You could use this to tell your app on the Android device that there's new content to fetch from the server, for example.

Comment: This is what iam looking for thank you so much. I will google for examples cuz i found google docx hard to understand without example.

Answer (score 0):

IP Addresses on mobile devices are pretty ephemeral.  In addition, to save on battery power, a lot of phones turn off the wifi antenna when it isn't being used.  And of course, internet connections are always spotty on mobile devices.

Because of this, it's usually a lot simpler for the device to ask the server "is there a file for me?".  A good way to do this on Android is to use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and have the device periodically check to see if there is a file that it should download - maybe once or twice a day.

Comment: yep but it's not good cuz that will consume date plan cuz it isnt enough for my application to check just twice or 10 time in a day. thanks any way